# Does redshift guarantee sequential inserting of identity column?

Tags: javascript, sql, .net, amazon-redshift, nestjs

Is there any way to guarantee sequence of id's in redshift? i.e every insertion is +1 from the max id.

Comment: No.  No database guarantees that as far as I know -- at least not any powerful database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there any workaround to this issue?

Comment: @JaredCowo Why do you need to guarantee sequential id's?  There's good reason (insertion rollbacks/deletes/etc) IDs aren't necessarily sequential.

Comment: @JaredCowo . . . Use `row_number()` when you query the table.

Comment: You cannot and should not predict nor dictate identity column values . If you [explained why you think you need to do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

From [Examples - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_examples.html):

> **Create a table with an IDENTITY column**
>
> The following example creates a table named `VENUE_IDENT`, which has an IDENTITY column named `VENUEID`. This column starts with 0 and increments by 1 for each record. `VENUEID` is also declared as the primary key of the table.

```sql
create table venue_ident(
  venueid bigint identity(0, 1),
  venuename varchar(100),
  venuecity varchar(30),
  venuestate char(2),
  venueseats integer,
  primary key(venueid)
);
```

See also: [Redshift - Identity column SEED-STEP with Insert statement](http://www.sqlhaven.com/identity-column-seed-step-with-insert-statements/)